# enum with same type as protocol method

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-protocols

I would like to introduce a protocol which would force my Enums to have variable `next` returning enum of the same type. I then would like to be able to call method to compare two enums.

```swift
protocol MySequenceProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var next: T { get }
}

func compareNext<T: MySequenceProtocol>(input: T, target: T) {
    if input.next == target {
        print("match")
    }
}
compareNext(input: Weekdays.monday.next, target: Weekdays.tuesday)
compareNext(input: Months.jan.next, target: Months.feb)
```

However, I'm having an error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T.T' and 'T'`

My full code with few enum examples:

```swift
protocol MySequenceProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var next: T { get }
}

enum Weekdays: MySequenceProtocol {
   case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
    
    var next: Weekdays {
        switch self {
        case .monday:
            return .tuesday
        default:
            return .monday
        }
    }
}

enum Months: MySequenceProtocol {
   case jan, feb, march
    
    var next: Months {
        switch self {
        case .jan:
            return .feb
        case .feb:
            return .march
        default:
            return .jan
        }
    }
}

func compareNext<T: MySequenceProtocol>(input: T, target: T) {
    if input.next == target { /// error here
        print("match")
    }
}
```

I feel like the problem is in constraining protocol to return the same `T`, however I'm not sure how to express it in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Your protocol declaration doesn't actually express your requirements correctly. Using an associatedType requirement for `next` makes it possible to conform with types whose `next` is of a different type than the conforming type itself.

What you actually need is `Self`, which refers to the conforming type.

```
protocol MySequenceProtocol {
    var next: Self { get }
}
```

Then you also need to specify that your generic type constraint `T` conforms to `Equatable` and make your that your enums actually conform to `Equatable`.

```
func compareNext<T: MySequenceProtocol>(input: T, target: T) where T: Equatable {
    if input.next == target {
        print("match")
    }
}

enum Weekdays: MySequenceProtocol, Equatable {
...
}

enum Months: MySequenceProtocol, Equatable {
...
}
```

You are also calling your `compareNext` function incorrectly. You should simply pass the enum case to it, you shouldn't call `next`, since the function itself already calls `next`.

```
compareNext(input: Weekdays.monday, target: Weekdays.tuesday)
compareNext(input: Months.jan, target: Months.feb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the error message more useful by using names other than just `T`:

```
protocol MySequenceProtocol {
    associatedtype Next
    var next: Next { get }
}

func compareNext<MSP: MySequenceProtocol>(input: MSP, target: MSP) {
    if input.next == target { /// error here
        print("match")
    }
}
```

What'll then get is:

> error: binary operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `MSP.Next` and `MSP`

Which makes it clear: there's no guarentee that `MSP` and its `Next` associated type are the same type, thus, they can't be compared with `==`.

The most salient fix is to just require `Next` to be the same as `Self`:

```
protocol MySequenceProtocol {
    associatedtype Next where Next == Self
    var next: Next { get }
}
```

Now of course, this is what a regular old `Self` requirement is for!

This now gives you a new error:

> error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MSP' operands

This makes sense, because you never expressed the requirement that `MSP` (or the type `MySequenceProtocol` to which it's constrained) are equatable. Fixing that:

```
func compareNext<MSP: MySequenceProtocol & Equatable>(input: MSP, target: MSP) {
    if input.next == target { /// error here
        print("match")
    }
}

compareNext(input: Weekdays.monday.next, target: Weekdays.tuesday)
compareNext(input: Months.jan.next, target: Months.feb)
```

Comment: There's no need for the associated type `Next`, you can simply declare the `next` property to be of type `Self`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Indeed, but I was hoping to show more of the progression from start to finish, making minimal changes, just to show how the error messages guide you to a solution

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm actually kind of surprised that `associatedtype Next where Next == Self` doesn't raise a warning for being redundant